# Unable to boot to live DVD on Mac PowerBook G4

Tags: installation, boot, mac, powerpc, livedvd

My mac is really old.  The hardware sucks, but so does the software. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit PowerPC on it, but whenever I try to boot to the live DVD, by either holding <kbd>C</kbd>' or <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>', nothing happens, and it boots up as normal. By holding <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>, I used to get a boot screen, but I don't get that now, when I started trying this DVD.

How do I boot to a DVD? It's not working! This is infuriating.

Computer Specs:

```
Hardware:
Model Name: PowerBook G4 12"
Model Identifier: PowerBook6,4
Processor Name: PowerPC G4 (1.1)
Processor Speed: 1.33 GHz
Number of CPUs: 1
L2 Cache (per CPU): 512 KB
Memory: 768 MB
Bus Speed: 167 MHz
Boot ROM Version: 4.8.3f1

Software:
System Version: Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L30)
Kernel Version: Darwin 9.8.0
Boot Mode: Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better using the Alternate Installer, but since Your Mac has low RAM, Lubuntu PPC may suit your system much better.
To save You time, get the Lubuntu 12.04 Alternate Installer here:
http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/lubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso

Comment: It would be good if you could give the person who asked the question a little more information, like where to download the other OS or where to find the alternative installer.